# OAuth2.0 deciding on authorization mode

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, django-rest-framework

Trying to decide on which auth model to use.  I have a cloud-based multi-tenant ERP app. These tenants will want to give access to some of their APIs to another one of our fat-client ERP systems and (potentially) other 3rd parties. Higher ups said no way should the OA client know a user and password. Conceptually this smells to me as "Auth Code", EXCEPT I am not sure how you can have a redirect_uri when the OA client is a fat-client.

Comment: If you have control over the "fat-client" then you could build the functionality into the client for Authentication. IMHO, Auth Code is the way to go. I would consider using OpenID-Connect and not "bare" OAuth.